# Do all relationships modeled in SQLAlchemy have to be bi-directional?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, relational-database

I am learning python and sqlalchemy and modelled this relationship between shops and locale. I get the error:

> InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't
>   proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper:
>   'Mapper|Shop|shop'. Original exception was: Mapper
>   'Mapper|Locale|locale' has no property 'shop'

when I try to retrieve a lolcale from the db.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, PrimaryKeyConstraint, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

    class Shop(maria.Base):
        __tablename__ = 'shop'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True }

        name = Column(String(25), primary_key=True)
        locale = Column(String, ForeignKey('locale.country'), primary_key=True)
        url = Column(String, nullable=False)

        country = relationship("Locale", back_populates='shop')

        def __repr__(self):
            return "{\n\tname:'%s',\n\tlocale:'%s',\n\turl:'%s'\n}" % (self.name, self.locale, self.url)

    class Locale(maria.Base):
        __tablename__ = 'locale'
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

        country = Column(String(50), primary_key=True)
        code = Column(String(11), primary_key=True)

        def __repr__(self):
            return "{\n\tcountry:'%s',\n\tcode:'%s'\n}" % (self.country, self.code)
```

Comment: No, leave out the `back_populates`, since `Locale` does not have the *shop* relationship attribute.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Tried and still get the same error. I should mention that I am do all this in the iPython interpreter

Comment: That's the problem, you're probably redefining the class over and over in your already broken session. Start from scratch, with the `back_populates` removed.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks. can you add it as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQLAlchemy ORM relationships are not required to be bi-directional. If using [`back_populates`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.back_populates) argument you are declaring it as such though. Using `back_populates` requires that you declare the other end as well:

> Takes a string name and has the same meaning as `backref`, except the complementing property is **not** created automatically, and instead **must be configured explicitly on the other mapper**. The complementing property should also indicate `back_populates` to this relationship to ensure proper functioning.

(Latter emphasis mine)

Since you've not declared the property at the other end, SQLAlchemy complains. Just remove the `back_populates` argument:

```
class Shop(maria.Base):
    ...
    country = relationship("Locale")
    ...
```