# SQLAlchemy Many-to-one unidirectional relationship

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am working with SQLAlchemy and I have a table I want to add, `order`, which references a currency table.

I want a foreign key relationship setup so the order points to a currency in the currency table, but I don't want the currency table to contain a list of orders which use that currency.  Most of the docs make me think that relationships go two ways, but I want something that is more one directional, that match raw SQL like:

```
CREATE TABLE order ... FOREIGN KEY(currency_id) REFERENCES currencies(id)
```

Is this possible with SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044089/do-all-relationships-modeled-in-sqlalchemy-have-to-be-bi-directional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply don't define a relationship on the other end, in your case "currency", and don't use `backref`. Relationships are actually unidirectional by default and you have to use `back_populates` etc. in order to make them bidirectional. This is covered in ["Basic Relationship Patterns"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html).